# issue with callback url

Tags: php, laravel

I am using php 7.2 and laravel I have issue with the callback url

this is the callback url

```
 $callbackUrl = route('ipn.coinPay');
```

and this is ipn.coinPay file

```
        $track = $request->custom;
    $status = $request->status;
    $amount1 = floatval($request->amount1);
    $currency1 = $request->currency1;




        if ($status>=-1 || $status==0)
        {
 $hnd = fopen("./live_test.txt", "a");

       fwrite($hnd, $track . ': test:' . $status . '| btc: ' . $amount1 .'| btc: ' . "\n");
            fclose($hnd);
        }
```

I want to make the callback URL write this file even the result is true or wrong

now why it doesn't make the file what is the reason

i try to change file premission but no luck

Comment: the `if()` condition is bit silly :)

Answer (score 0):

The API is trying to post the data on your IPN callback URL and there can be an issue of the CSRF token error. So check the log file and make sure you have excluded the callback URL from [CSRF verification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris).

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*', //Add your callback URL on this array
    ];
}
```

Comment: can you give me your email or facebook to contact you i don't understand

Comment: Check my updated answer. For detail visit the laravel document link posted in answer.

Comment: Can you provide me the URL of the documentation?